# Make piece of code run only when activity opens for first time

Tags: android

In the app I am making I want a piece of code to run only when the activity is first opened.

For example I open my app, Then click the the animals activity for the first time. This code should run

```
stringListCounter = randInt(0, 100);
```

The code takes place here:

```
// What Happens When Activity Starts//
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animals);

    // What Number List Starts At//
    stringListCounter = randInt(0, 100);

    // Grab Audio And Convert//
    audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // Link Button Team One to Activity_Animals//
    t1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Team1);
    t1.setEnabled(false);
    t1.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Link Button Number One to Activity_Animals//
    number1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Number1);
    number1.setText(String.valueOf(Category.team_one));

    // Link Button Number Two to Activity_Animals//
    number2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Number2);
    number2.setText(String.valueOf(Category.team_two));

    // Link Button Team Two to Activity_Animals//
    t2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Team2);
    t2.setEnabled(false);
    t2.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Link TextView Timer to Activity_Animals//
    Timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Timer);

    // Link Button Next to Activity_Animals//
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Link TextView Word to Activity_Animals//
    word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Word);

    // Create Media Player//
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beep1);

    // Create Media Player 2//
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.gj);

}
```

Then from now forwards this code should not run until the app is completely destroyed. So basically this piece of code should run once every time the app is opened. This is really confusing to explain so if you don't understand Ill try to explain another way Thanks.

Comment: put this code in OnCreate of activity

Comment: It is there, the code will run every time the activity is opened though. I only want that piece of code to run once. Then not run until the app is completely opened again

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to achieve this. For example, you can put that code in the onCreate of an Application-extending class, and make a getter/setter (or if you want, a public field) to the field you put that integer.

```js
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public String[] mStringListCounter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mStringListCounter = randInt(0, 100);
    }
}
```

And then getting the result in the other classes:

```
int stringListCounter = ((MainApplication)getApplication()).mStringListCounter;
```

**EDIT:** Naturally you must declare your Application activity name in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
...
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
...
```